# lapply and dplyr combination to process nested data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have a list of dataframes inside of my folder directory which I want to process for analyses. I read them by using inside of `lapply` function first, then I want to process its columns and order its rows by grouping. Therefore most of times I needed to combine `dplyr` and `lapply` functions to process faster of my data.
I looked through out the web and check some books but most of the examples are easy ones and do not cover combination of these two functions.

Here is the sample code which I'm using:

```
files <- mixedsort(dir(pattern = "*.txt",full.names = FALSE)) # to read data

data <-  lapply(files,function(x){
tmp <- read.table(file=x, fill=T, sep = "\t", dec=".", header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
df <- tmp [!grepl(c("AC"),tmp $V1),]
new.df <- select(df, V1:V26)
new.df <- apply(new.df, function(x){ x[11:26] <- x[11:26]/10000;x })
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Here is the reproducible example which looks like my data. Lets say I want to process 2nd and 3rd column of my `dat` and group by `let` column. When I try to put below `fun` command inside of `data` code above I got error. Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
dat <- lapply(1:3, function(x)data.frame(let=sample(letters,4),a=sort(runif(20,0,10000),decreasing=TRUE), b=sort(runif(20,0,10000),decreasing=TRUE), c=rnorm(20),d=rnorm(20)))

fun <- lapply(dat, function(x){x[2:3] <-x[2:3] /10000; x})
```

Comment: The format of an `apply` function is `apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)` where `MARGIN` is either `1` (rows) or `2` (columns). You are missing the `margin` part in your `apply` function.

Comment: @Jaap ok I put  `2` after `new.df` but I got error "Error in x[11:26]/10000 : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments to your question, the apply function was causing the error. However I don't think apply is what you want, because it aggregates your dataframe.

using just dplyr-syntax your problem can be solved like this:

```
tmp %>%
  filter(!grepl("AC",V1)) %>%
  select(V1:V26) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(./1000), V11:V26)
```